# Scrape Product Rating that is shown as %-width of five stars

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape the average product rating from the page https://www.gonser.ch/.
I saw that the rating is shown as the percentual width of how much of the 5 possible stars are filled (in gold colour).
With my code I somehow can extract some of the width, but not exactly the value I want:

```
page <- read_html("http://www.gonser.ch/13879")

# extract the div element
div_element <- html_nodes(page, ".feedback-stars-overlay-wrap") 

# Extract the "style" attribute from the element
style_attribute <- html_attr(div_element, "style") 

# extract the width value
width_value <- str_extract(style_attribute, "width: ([0-9.]+)%") 

# Convert to a numeric value
width <- as.numeric(width_value)
```

As a result, I get 9 different values for `style_attribute`, from which 2 are NAs and the others are not the value that I see when I inspect the page (with this example it would be width: 91.6% at the moment of this post)

Does anyone know how to correctly extract only the width of the average star rating?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

"https://www.gonser.ch/13879/" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements(".feedback-stars-overlay-wrap") %>%
  html_attr("style") %>%
  str_remove_all("[^\\.0-9]") %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  na.omit() %>% 
  mean()

[1] 95.51429
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. with your code i was able to reproduce your outcome, but i could not apply it to single product page (as for example www.gonser.ch/13879). It would still give me 9 values of which 2 ar NAs. As far as i can tell the 2 NAs are the average rating for the actual product and the other 7 values are from the products underneath. I only need the width of the average product rating of the actual product. Do you have any idea how your code could be applied on the product page mentioned above?